# Is it possible to use res.sendFile() and res.redirect() together in Express ReactJS application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am working on ReactJS/ExpressJS application and implemented SSR. Now I am getting a problem, I want to redirect my website's every route to www. I am sending static file already and want to redirect every route as well.

**Here is my code:**

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.headers.host.match(/^www/) !== null ) {
    const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../build', 'index.html');
    res.sendFile(filePath);
  } else {
    res.redirect('http://www.mywebsite.com/'+ req.url);
    const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../build', 'index.html');
    res.sendFile(filePath);
  }
})
```

But it is not working, If anywone help me out I will reallly appreciate.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use re.sendFile() and res.redirect() together in Express ReactJS application?

No, you can't do that.  You only get to send one response to the request.  So, you have to pick either `res.redirect()` or `res.sendFile()`.  You can't send both.  If you try to send both, whichever one is first will be the response that is sent to the client and the second one will be ignored by Express.

FYI, the whole idea of a redirect is that the client will then request that new url from your server and you will THEN render the page that goes with that new url.  So, it doesn't make sense to send a redirect url which will cause the browser to immediately request a new url and then display that page AND to send content that will never be displayed.

If you describe what your actual use case is, perhaps we can advise on a more appropriate solution, but in direct answer to your question, no - you can't send both.

Comment: Actually I want to force redirect my whole website to www, but due to ssr I also need to send static file to pretend error like error /get somepage.

Comment: or can you advice me how can I achieve that in ReactJS/ExpressJS website.

Comment: @JagdeeshKumar - Just redirect to the appropriate www url.  The browser will then request that new URL and will render that page.  That's how a redirect works.  You can't have a pretend error and a server-side redirect.  You could render an error page and then have that page have a client-side redirect in it, but I don't know why you'd do that.  Why show the user an error when they are just going to be automatically redirected to www anyway.

Comment: You mean we do not need to take care of SSR error just need to redirect to www right?

Comment: @JagdeeshKumar - What is a "SSR error"?  I'm not familiar with that phrase.  "Server-side redirect"?  "Server-side render"?  Just redirect and let the browser load the redirected page and fire up your app from there.

Comment: its Server Side Rendering. I have checked website is not forcing redirect to www.  quickcarfinance.co.uk/privacy-policy its the URL

Comment: @JagdeeshKumar - You are not redirecting the top level `https://quickcarfinance.co.uk/privacy-policy` URL.  But, your code is attempting to redirect a bunch of resources in that page so the redirect code appears to be doing it's job.  Do you have this `app.all(...)` route as your FIRST route?  Even before any route that might serve your main page?

Comment: No! its at the end of page.

Comment: @JagdeeshKumar - Another problem is that you're redirecting to a URL like `'https://www.quickcarfinance.co.uk//fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0`.  See the `//` after the host.  That won't work.

Comment: @JagdeeshKumar - You need to change: `'http://www.mywebsite.com/'+ req.url);` to `'http://www.mywebsite.com'+ req.url);`

Comment: @JagdeeshKumar - If it's at the end, then some other route is grabbing the request before your `app.all()` gets to do its thing.  This needs to be probably the first middleware you have.

Comment: its just a content based website I did not use any middleware, and when I have used app.all() at the top its giving me error too many redirects :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213741/discussion-between-jagdeesh-kumar-and-jfriend00).

Comment: Well, you have to show me more code.  I can't help you fix what I can't see.

Comment: Can we talk in chat instead?

Comment: I waited in chat for 8 minutes.  You weren't there.  Now I have to go.